# Sprite texture not repeating unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I want to repeat texture on Quad but it is not repeating
here is my code

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Track : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed;
    Vector2 Offset;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Offset = new Vector2 (0, Time.deltaTime * speed);

        GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.mainTextureOffset = Offset;

    }
}
```

please someone help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have logic problem when assigning value to `Offset`.
Explanation below:

```
void Update () {
    // Assume that Offset's value is { 2, 3 }
    Offset = new Vector2 (0, Time.deltaTime * speed);
    // Assume Time.DeltaTime's value is 0.12f
    // Assume speed's value is 10
    // Now to figure out the problem ( 0.12f * 10f = 1.2f )
    // Offset's value is now 1.2f
    GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.mainTextureOffset = Offset;
}
```

As you can see now, you're only assigning the value which will be almost the same every time. The value can vary only a bit just because of `Time.DeltaTime` will yield delta time between frames which can be approximately `0.0016f`.

So to make it clear, you should not rely on `Time.DeltaTime` because it's almost constant value. First try to initialize your `Offset` in `Start` or `Awake` method:

```
void Start() {
    Offset = GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTextureOffset;
}
```

Then inside of your `Update` method you can just increase `X` value :

```
void Update() {
    Offset = new Vector2(Offset[0] + (Time.DeltaTime * speed), Offset[1]); 
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTextureOffset = Offset;
}
```